# flutter null safety from prefs.setStringList -> error : the argument list<String?> can't be assigned to the parameter type List <String>

Tags: flutter

Hello I try to make null safety migration, but have a probleme with

```
 prefs.setStringList("save_list_autre2",save_list.toList());
```

the error is : the argument list<String?> can't be assigned to the parameter type List

```
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r'(...)');
var save_list= regExp.allMatches(decrypted).map((z) => z.group(0));
if(regExp.allMatches(decrypted)==null ){    
  [...]    
} else {
  prefs.setStringList("save_list_autre2",save_list.toList());  
}
```

I add `.toString()` from `save_list= regExp.allMatches(decrypted).map((z) => z.group(0).toString());`

the error is removed but I don't know if it's the good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `z.group(0)` the `group` method could return null if there was no group with the given index (0 in this case). so dart thinks you might have some null values on your list of strings.

The reality is that you *shouldn't* get any null values because you are passing a 0. So to tell dart that the method isn't returning null, use the `!` operator:

```
regExp.allMatches(decrypted)
  .map((z) => z.group(0)!)
```

If, by some chance, you happened to have any null values, this code will not work (as I said, I believe you won't but what do I know? I've never used regexes with dart)

If that's the case, you first need to filter the null values and then use the `!`:

```
regExp.allMatches(decrypted)
  .map((z) => z.group(0))
  .where((v) => v != null) // filter out null values
  .map((v) => v!); // let dart know you don't have any null values.
```

Hopefully that's enough to fix the problem